# How can I bind text to an SQL IN statement

Tags: android, c++, sql, c, java-native-interface

How can I bind text to an '**SQL IN**` statement?

```
char *sql = "SELECT "
"ENTITY_GUID " \
"FROM ENTITY_TABLE WHERE "
"ENTITY_OWNER_GUID IN (?)";

int rc = sqlite3_prepare(db, sql, -1, &stmt, 0);

sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 1, (const char *) char_sql_IN, -1, SQLITE_STATIC);
```

**`char_sql_IN`** prints `'26', '42', '43'` to console

**That is :**

```
char *sql = "SELECT "
"ENTITY_GUID " \
"FROM ENTITY_TABLE WHERE "
"ENTITY_OWNER_GUID IN (?)";

int rc = sqlite3_prepare(db, sql, -1, &stmt, 0);

sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 1, (const char *) char_sql_IN, -1, SQLITE_STATIC);

if (rc != SQLITE_OK) {
    fprintf(stderr, "SQL error: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
}

rc = sqlite3_step(stmt);

while (rc == SQLITE_ROW) {
    long entityGUID = sqlite3_column_int(stmt, 0);
    rc = sqlite3_step(stmt);
}
```

Thank you all.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Sorry. It is Android with JNI.

Comment: Do you know the number of parameters beforehand, or at least the maximum number which there might be?  This is a hairy question to handle, in any language/database, by the way +1.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen yes I do. `'26', '42', '43'` are translated from a `List<Long>`, then passed to `C` as a `Java String` via JNI